# Spacing issues with align, aligned and intertext

Tags: spacing, align, amsmath

I have the following snippet:

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
        ab &= abcdefghij&&ABCDEF \\
           &            &&-ZYXW
    \end{aligned}
    \intertext{not also that}
    ab &= defghijklmn
\end{align}
```

[image]

This has a few spacing problems. First, there is the gap between `j` and `A` and in the next line before the `-`. Second, the second equation is misaligned. It should have been aligned at the `=` of the first equation. How can I fix this?

Comment: From where did you expect that the alignment inside aligned would match that of the rest of align? Since the first row seen by align has no right hand part (three is no & in thst row, thst align sees) the item in the first row is a single left hand object, these are right aligned and thus aligns correctly with the ab in row 2 (seen by align). Regarding the space of j and A see the alignedat env (remember it takes a mandatory integer argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you're trying to obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        ab &= \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
            abcdefghij&ABCDEF \\
           &-ZYXW
           \end{alignedat} \\
    \shortintertext{note also that}
    ab &= defghijklmn
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]